# How can I connect my Raspberry Pi B 8GB RAM with Ubuntu x64 installed to a laptop display using VNC?

Tags: raspberrypi, arm

How can I connect my Raspberry Pi B 8gb RAM with Ubuntu x64 installed to a laptop display using VNC? The client has to use VNC viewer (the easiest way).

On Raspberry Pi, OS works just fine, but on Ubuntu, I don't know how. I used putty and VNC viewer to do it.

Comment: Please specify the version of Ubuntu that you are running.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is install VNC Server on the host and view that on your laptop. If not, please clarify your question. In that case, you can use [this](https://hackernoon.com/installation-of-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-1cf035370bd3) website to achieve this. It does a good job at explaining the process, better than I can explain writing it here.

If the Ubuntu version that the website is too old, try using [this](https://linuxconfig.org/vnc-server-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux) method. It uses TightVNC and is supported by Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: The OP did not specify the version of Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi, however I think that the link you provided needs an update.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I revised the answer with a newer method as well as kept the old one. The OP never specified the Ubuntu version like you mentioned, so I still kept the link that corresponds to an older Ubuntu version.